# Virtual NIC interfaces go down when physical NIC doesn't have IP address

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ifconfig

I am creating two virtual interfaces from a physical NIC interface using SR-IOV:

```
echo 2 > /sys/class/net/PHYSICAL_INTERFACE/device/sriov_numvfs
```

I want to use one of the virtual interfaces with a DPDK program. It seems that a DPDK program can only use a virtual interface if the virtual interface's corresponding physical interface isn't bound to anything.

Thus, my idea was to unbind the physical interface and use the second virtual interface to SSH into (my machine has only one port plugged into the network).

However, even when I am careful to assign the second virtual interface an IP address and then SSH in via the second virtual interface, unbinding the physical interface from an IP address seems to remove the machine from the network:

```
ifconfig PHYSICAL_INTERFACE 0.0.0.0 up
```

Is it possible to do what I trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The assumption from the question:  `It seems that a DPDK program can only use a virtual interface if the virtual interface's corresponding physical interface isn't bound to anything.`

Answer: this is not true, Using X710 I have PF with kernel and VF interfaces with DPDK. Only criteria is to use VF MAC address while sending packets to DPDK (basic redirects to VF)

For any VF to work one has to either bind wth Kernel driver or DPDK PMD (igb_uio or vfio-pci). Unbind the PF driver from Kernel, the VF to PF mailbox connectivity is lost and VF is no longer valid. Hence for any VF to be used it has to be bind with Kernel or DPDK in case of X710.